# Conductor of a character

Tags: analytic-number-theory

We know, a character $\chi$ mod $q$ is induced by a primitive character $\chi^{*}$ mod $q^{*}$. I have the following questions.

1. If $\chi$ is non principal, can $\chi^{*}$ be principal?
2. Let $\chi$ be a character mod $q$. Can we say $\chi$ is principal iff conductor of $\chi=1?$
3. If $\chi$ be the principal character mod $q$. What is the primitive character mod $q^{*}$ which induces it?

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Notice that $\chi(n)=\chi^*(n)$ when $(n,q)=1$ and $\chi(n)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: For the first two, you can conclude very quickly by writing down a definition of being principal. (The answers are "No" and "Yes", unless you have a different definition than what I think is standard). For the third, it's the character mod $1$ where $\chi(n) \equiv 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already figured them out.